# DjangoSEO & Django 1.8 usage

Tags: django, django-migrations

I use Django 1.8 and Python 2.7. Recently I tried to use [DjangoSEO](http://django-seo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/contents.html) package in my project. I accomplished everything according to [this tutorial](http://django-seo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction/tutorial.html), but finally command `python manage.py makemigrations` doesn't detect any changes and command `python manage.py migrate` doesn't make any tables. In admin panel I can see my SEO models, but there are no tables made in my database. Also I figured out, that [DjangoSEO is not compatible with Django 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29015988/django-seo-setting-up-models-arent-loaded-yet/29024602#29024602). So my question is: can I use this package with Django 1.8? How to make it make migrations?
By the way, I store my seo.py in the project directory, not in the directory with any app.

Comment: To create migrations for a new app, do `python manage.py <appname>`. However, if you look at the [repository](https://github.com/willhardy/django-seo) for Django SEO, there haven't been any updates for a couple of years. If it doesn't work with Django 1.7, then it isn't going to work with Django 1.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this problem. Now it can work with Django 1.8.

1) There is an update of DjangoSEO package [here](https://github.com/romansalin/django-seo). I had to install this one.

2) I had to create `urls.py` in the directory of any `app`, not in the directory of my project. So it is visible in admin panel and migrations are being made.

Comment: I had the same exact issue that you had i was struggling a lot i was about to give up with this framework until i read your comment that there was a newer version for this package so i went for it and it is working, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

try using following way :

1- delete database

2- delete *.pyc files in **__pycache_** folder

3- delete migration files in **migrations** folder

4- python manage.py makemigrations

5- python manage.py sqlmigrate  0001

6- reset server

Comment: No tables, migration folders are created. So I have nothing to delete.